# Custom Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I am trying to create a content slider which will be governed by a scroll bar. I want the scroll bar to look like this [image: Requirement]

First of let me give u my HTML and Css Layout

**HTML**

```
 <div class="service-main-content">
        <div id="service-display">
            <!-- Start Page -->
            <div id="service-showcase" class="service-content">
                DISPLAY ALL SERVICES
            </div>

            <!-- Web Services -->
            <div id="service-web" class="service-content">
                Content 1
            </div>

            <!-- Software Development -->
            <div id="service-app" class="service-content">
                Content 2
            </div>

            <!-- Network Solutions -->
            <div id="service-network" class="service-content">
                Content 3
            </div>

            <!-- Call Center -->
            <div id="service-call" class="service-content">
                Content 4

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.service-main-content{
    padding-top:8%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;


}

.service-content{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:3900;
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;

}
#service-display{
    position: absolute;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    scrollbar-face-color: #b46868;
}
```

**JS**

```
var win_width = $(window).width();
var win_height = $(window).height();
$.fn.set_left = function() {
    var s_divs = ["#service-showcase", "#service-web", "#service-app", "#service-network", "#service-call"];
    left = 0;
    jQuery.each(s_divs, function(i, val) {

        $(val).css("left", left + "px");
        left = left + win_width;
    });

};

$(document).ready(function() {

    win_height = win_height / 100 * 65;
    $(".service-content").css("min-width", win_width + "px");
    $("#service-display").css("min-height", win_height + "px");
    $(this).set_left();

    $('#service-display').jScrollPane({
        showArrows : true,
        horizontalDragMinWidth : 5,
        horizontalDragMaxWidth : 50
    });
    //
    // $("#service-display").mCustomScrollbar({
    // horizontalScroll : true,
    // //scrollEasing : "easeOutQuart",
    // //autoDraggerLength : false
    // });

    //$("#service-display").slider();

});
```

I tried a few Plugins Namely:

- JScrollPane
- mCustomScrollbar

As shown above in the JS code.
 This is the output I am getting for JScrollPane

**JScrollPane**
[image: JSCROLLPANE OUTPUT]

I case of mCustomScroll , all my content is hidden and I see the default scrollbar.

Please guide me through this. I would be really very grateful.

Thanking You

Comment: Hi,
Did you tried jQuery UI Slider - http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll ?

Comment: Yes I did. I didn't get the desired result.